# How do you get dates on the start on the specified month? (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
# FEB
# configuring the figure and plot space
fig, lx = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,10))

# converting the Series into str so the data can be plotted
wd = df2['Unnamed: 1']
wd = wd.astype(float)

# adding the x and y axes' values
lx.plot(list(df2.index.values), wd)

# defining what the labels will be 
lx.set(xlabel='Day', ylabel='Weight', title='Daily Weight February 2022')

# defining the date format 
date_format = DateFormatter('%m-%d')
lx.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
lx.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
```

Values I would like the x-axis to have:

['2/4', '2/5', '2/6', '2/7', '2/8', '2/9', '2/10', '2/11', '2/12', '2/13', '2/14', '2/15', '2/16', '2/17', '2/18', '2/19', '2/20', '2/21', '2/22', '2/23', '2/24', '2/25', '2/26', '2/27']

Values on the x-axis:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vszgR.png)

It is giving me the right number of values just not the right labels. I have tried to specify the start and end with xlim=['2/4', '2/27], however that did seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be great to see how your `df2` actually looks, but from your code snippet, it looks like it has weights recorded but not the corresponding dates.

How about prepare a data frame that has dates in it?

(Also, since this question is tagged with `seaborn` too, I'm going to use Seaborn, but the same idea should work.)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import seaborn.objects as so
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

sns.set_theme()
```

Create an index with the dates starting from 4 Feb with the number of days we have weight recorded.

```py
index = pd.date_range(start="2/4/2022", periods=df.count().Weight, name="Date")
```

Then with [Seaborn's object interface](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/objects_interface.html) (v0.12+), we can do:

```py
(
    so.Plot(df2.set_index(index), x="Date", y="Weight")
        .add(so.Line())
        .scale(x=so.Temporal().label(formatter=DateFormatter('%m-%d')))
        .label(title="Daily Weight February 2022")
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response and great explanation! df2 is in the array of the x-axis I outlined in the initial post, but I have figured out the issue. Since the labels were already formatted the way I needed them to be, I did not need 'DateFormatter' nor 'set_major_locator'. And yes, I should've shown more code. I had initialized the index to start with feb 4. Anyway, your response is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this solution. Very simple. I just added mdates.WeekdayLocator() to set_major_formatter. I overlooked this when I was going through the matplotlib docs. But happy to have found this solution.

Comment: Actually, I keep getting a TyperError, 'formatter' must be an instance of matplotlib.ticker.Formatter, not a matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator. However, it is plotting exactly what I need.